# Prevent active kubernetes pod from terminating

Tags: kubernetes

We have a pod which serves HTTP traffic. When we update the image version of the parent deployment is there a way to prevent the pod from terminating until all current connections have finished?

We are not looking to inject an arbitrary delay but rather to intelligently monitor current client connections during the rolling update phase to ensure they are not terminated prematurely.

Comment: I'm in need of the exact same thing! Did you find a solution? There are things like `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` or `lifecycle.preStop`, but this doesn't seem to work that exact way.